# How to implement a multi-layered listview with filtering?

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter, layer

At the moment, I've implemented a multi-layered Pinned list view whereby it subclasses a linearlayout with a listview in it. It's simply a header with a listview in it, to keep the header on top. I've implemented three different adapters to use with this. A BuildingListAdapter, a FloorListAdapter and a RoomListAdapter.

They each sit on top of each other, and I think I've overcomplicated it and now it kinda works, kinda doesn't. Simple idea, really. Comes up with the buildings attributed to a project. If you choose a building, it filters the floors and displays the floors in that building, and if you choose a floor, it displays the rooms of the floor. Buuut! It's very weird and picky about it sometimes. The main problem I have is when it scrolls. If I click on a building, it highlights it green to show it's been selected, when I scroll down and up again on the list, it is no longer green. I was just wondering if anyone's got a clean, similar example to this, since I feel like scrapping all my code on this as it just seems bad and hard to maintain.

```
public class BuildingListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private Activity context;
private ArrayList<Building> buildingCollection;
public FloorListAdapter floorAdapter;
private DataSource datasource;

/**
 * @param context
 * @param buildingCollection
 */
public BuildingListAdapter(Activity context,
        ArrayList<Building> buildingCollection) {
    this.context = context;
    this.buildingCollection = buildingCollection;
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param floorAdapter
 * @param buildingList
 */
public BuildingListAdapter(Activity context, FloorListAdapter floorAdapter,
        ArrayList<Building> buildingList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.datasource = new DataSource(context);
    datasource.open();
    this.floorAdapter = floorAdapter;
    this.buildingCollection = buildingList;
}

/**
 * @return
 */
public FloorListAdapter getFloorCollection() {
    return floorAdapter;
}

/**
 * @param floorCollection
 */
public void setFloorCollection(FloorListAdapter floorCollection) {
    this.floorAdapter = floorCollection;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
 */
public int getCount() {
    return buildingCollection.size();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
 */
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return buildingCollection.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.BaseAdapter#getItemViewType(int)
 */
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void update()
{
    buildingCollection = datasource.getBuildings();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {
    final Building selectedBuilding = buildingCollection.get(position);
    final String buildingDescription = "Building "
            + selectedBuilding.getId();
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_child_item, null);
    }

    TextView buildingDescriptionView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.locationDescription);
    buildingDescriptionView.setText(buildingDescription);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!selectedBuilding.selected)
            {
                for (Building building : buildingCollection) 
                {
                    if (building.getId() != selectedBuilding.getId())
                    {
                        building.setSelected(false);
                        datasource.setColumnTrue(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_BUILDING,
                                false, building.getId(),
                                SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BUILDING_ID);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                    parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(
                            R.color.white);
                }
                selectedBuilding.setSelected(true);
                datasource.setColumnTrue(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_BUILDING, true,
                        selectedBuilding.getId(),
                        SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BUILDING_ID);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);

            } 
            else 
            {
                selectedBuilding.setSelected(false);
                datasource.setColumnTrue(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_BUILDING, false,
                        selectedBuilding.getId(),
                        SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BUILDING_ID);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            }
            if (floorAdapter != null) {
                floorAdapter.filter();
                floorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                floorAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.BaseAdapter#getViewTypeCount()
 */
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.BaseAdapter#isEnabled(int)
 */
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

}

That's one of my adapters, and should be enough to tell you the state of it all.

This is my LocationView, where they're each held, each one has an add button, where you can add a new building, floor or room where it simply adds to a dropdown of the things it can be part of.

```
public class LocationView extends LinearLayout {

List<String> groupList;
ArrayList<Building> buildingList;
ArrayList<Floor> floorList;
ArrayList<Location> roomList;
String projectNo;
DataSource datasource;

public LocationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_view, this);
    datasource = new DataSource(context);
    datasource.open();
}

/**
 * Populates the list view with an overview of the Post Survey Records
 * Currently in the Database
 */
/**
 * @param context
 * @param activity
 * @param projectNo
 */
public void updateListView(Context context, Activity activity,
        String projectNo) {

    loadBuildingChild();
    loadFloorChild();
    loadRoomChild();

    final LocationListAdapter locationListAdapter = new LocationListAdapter(activity,
            floorList);
    final FloorListAdapter floorListAdapter = new FloorListAdapter(
            activity, buildingList, locationListAdapter);

    PinnedListView buildingView = (PinnedListView) findViewById(R.id.buildng);
    buildingView.setHeader("Buildings");
    ListView buildingListView = (ListView) buildingView
            .findViewById(R.id.list);
    buildingListView.setAdapter(new BuildingListAdapter(activity,
            floorListAdapter, buildingList));

    PinnedListView floorView = (PinnedListView) findViewById(R.id.floor);
    floorView.setHeader("Floors");
    final ListView floorListView = (ListView) floorView
            .findViewById(R.id.list);
    floorListView.setAdapter(floorListAdapter);

    PinnedListView roomView = (PinnedListView) findViewById(R.id.room);
    roomView.setHeader("Rooms");
    ListView roomListView = (ListView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    roomListView.setAdapter(locationListAdapter);

    setAddBuilding(buildingView);
    setAddFloor(floorView, buildingList, floorListAdapter);
    setAddRoom(roomView, floorList, locationListAdapter);


}

/**
 * @param buildingView
 */
private void setAddBuilding(PinnedListView buildingView) {
    ImageView add = (ImageView) buildingView.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final BuildingDialog buildingDialog = new BuildingDialog(
                    getContext());
            buildingDialog.show();

            Button cancelButton = (Button) buildingDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    buildingDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button addButton = (Button) buildingDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.addButton);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText buildingEdit = (EditText) buildingDialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.buildingEdit);
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BUILDING_NAME,
                            buildingEdit.getText().toString());
                    contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SITE_ID, 1);
                    datasource.commitRecord(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_BUILDING,
                            contentValues);
                    buildingDialog.dismiss();
                    loadBuildingChild();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

/**
 * @param buildings
 */
private void loadBuildingChild() {
    buildingList = datasource.getBuildings();
}

/**
 * 
 */
private void loadFloorChild() {
    floorList = new ArrayList<Floor>();
    floorList = datasource.getFloors();
}

/**
 * 
 */
private void loadRoomChild() {
    roomList = new ArrayList<Location>();

    roomList = datasource.getLocations();

}

/**
 * @param floorView
 * @param buildingCollection
 * @param adapter
 */
private void setAddFloor(PinnedListView floorView, final ArrayList<Building> buildingCollection, final FloorListAdapter adapter ) {
    ImageView add = (ImageView) floorView.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final FloorDialog floorDialog = new FloorDialog(getContext());
            floorDialog.show();

            final Spinner buildingSpinner = (Spinner) floorDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.buildingSpinner);
            ArrayList<String> buildingTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Building building : buildingCollection) {
                buildingTexts.add(building.buildingDescription);
            }
            ArrayAdapter buildingAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, buildingTexts);
            buildingAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            buildingSpinner.setAdapter(buildingAdapter);

            Button cancelButton = (Button) floorDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    floorDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button addButton = (Button) floorDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.addButton);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText floorNameEdit = (EditText) floorDialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.floorNameEdit);

                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    int buildingId = buildingCollection.get(
                            buildingSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition())
                            .getId();
                    contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FLOOR_NUMBER,
                            datasource.getMaxFloorNo(buildingId) + 1);
                    contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BUILDING_ID,
                            buildingId);
                    contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FLOOR_NAME,
                            "Building " + buildingId
                                    + floorNameEdit.getText().toString());
                    datasource.commitRecord(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_FLOOR,
                            contentValues);
                    adapter.filter();
                    floorDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}

/**
 * @param roomView
 * @param floorCollection
 * @param adapter
 */
private void setAddRoom(final PinnedListView roomView, final ArrayList<Floor> floorCollection, final LocationListAdapter adapter ) {
    ImageView addRoom = (ImageView) roomView.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    addRoom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final LocationDialog roomDialog = new LocationDialog(getContext());
            final Spinner floorSpinner = (Spinner) roomDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.floorSpinner);
            ArrayList<String> floorTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Floor floor : floorCollection) {
                floorTexts.add(floor.getFloorName());
            }
            ArrayAdapter buildingAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                    roomView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    floorTexts);
            buildingAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            floorSpinner.setAdapter(buildingAdapter);
            for (Floor floor : floorCollection) {
                if (floor.isSelected()) {
                    floorSpinner.setSelection(floorCollection.indexOf(floor));
                }
            }

            roomDialog.show();

            Button cancelButton = (Button) roomDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    roomDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button addButton = (Button) roomDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.addButton);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    EditText roomNameEdit = (EditText) roomDialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.roomNameEdit);

                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    Floor floor = floorCollection.get(floorSpinner
                            .getSelectedItemPosition());
                    contentValues
                            .put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LOCATION_NUMBER,
                                    datasource.getMaxFloorNo(floor
                                            .getFloorId()) + 1);
                    contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FLOOR_ID,
                            floor.getFloorId());
                    contentValues.put(
                            SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LOCATION_DESCRIPTION,
                            "Building " + floor.getBuildingID()
                                    + floor.getFloorName() + " "
                                    + roomNameEdit.getText().toString());
                    datasource.commitRecord(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_LOCATION,
                            contentValues);
                    // roomCollection.add(datasource.getLatestLocation(floor.getFloorId()));
                    adapter.filter();
                    roomDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });

}
}
```

If you would like any further information on the code, or my intents, please just ask. 
**ANY** and all criticisms are welcome, I'd really like to clean this up properly.

I have to use a similar method for another part but it'll be even more complicated, so I don't want to move on there unless I can make it good in this part.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** The main thing I want from this is a good approach to filtering based on parent results. The layout, albeit flawed and the only thing that doesn't work well in my implementation is of lesser importance.

**EDIT 2:** As per requested, r.layout.location_view.xml, although it's not much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/locationView"
>
<com.ohs.mobile.app.PinnedListView 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buildng"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />


<com.ohs.mobile.app.PinnedListView 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/floor"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
/>

<com.ohs.mobile.app.PinnedListView 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/room"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: *when I scroll down and up again on the list, it is no longer green.* - and you don't see that color in other positions? Can you also post the layout with the tree lists(`R.layout.location_view`)?

Comment: You didn't answered my first question. You set the color in the `onClick` callback but I don't see setting the proper color at the `getView()` method level(try adding `v.setBackgroundResource(building.selected ? R.color.green : R.color.white);` at the end of the `getView()` method). Also, you could improve the current list setup.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't see it in other positions, no. It shows about 2 items at a time. I've fixed that, since. I simply set if it's selected in the onClick now, instead. And then just do what you said at the end of it. Idk why I did it that way originally.